# How to edit rowSpan of cell of report in BIRT?

Tags: eclipse, report, birt

I created a report (.rptdesign) in eclipse/BIRT and added a Grid and some rows in it. I want to change the rowSpan of 1st cell in 1st row to 3. But in properties window, the property is 1:inherited and won't allow me to edit the value. I tried different combinations of width and height (in, %..) and other properties but can't figure out this behavior. 
I spent hours and there is barely any resource available online or on official site. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create a grid with rows- all cells are equal in width. Now what you can do is **merge the cells together** that will create the rowspan/colspan like this -

**Please click on image to see steps**

[image]

After merging it will look like this -
[image]

You can get more information here : [eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc%2Fbirt%2Ffm-HowToMergeTableOrGridCells.html)

Comment: Thank you. And thanks for the reference guide. It was so much difficult to find help for this report tool.

Comment: No problem. I know, there are not many resources for birt online and it takes a lot of trial and error. Good luck with your report!

Answer (score 1):

You just mark several cells in the layout editor, then "merge cells" in the context menu. To split a block of merged cells again, use "split cells" in the context menu.